# dollar sign in variable using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

My requirement is to find id match with 'vrr' so I use * for it, but it is not working with dollar any guess why this is not working?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vrrcss">you</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    $('[id$*=vrr]').text('me')
})
```

Comment: You're saying "but it is not working with my dollar". What prompted you to put it in there? Surely, it works without it?

Answer (score 5):

[`$=` matches attributes that *end* with the specified value.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) `'vrrcss'` does not end with `'vrr'`.

Use [`^=` (attribute starts with)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) or [`*=` (attribute contains)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead.

Comment: that should be `^=` *or* `*=`, right; not `^*=`?

Comment: @DavidHedlund thanks, fixed `:)` was typing too quickly.

Comment: sure thing. +1, btw. same typo for `$*` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text of the element "vrr", try the [following](http://jsfiddle.net/jYapV/), or just...

```
$("[id^=vrr]").text('Me');
```